# How can I create a dictionary showing which entries in column a are associated with which entries in column b in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to understand the relationships between the variables in columns A and B. They are string variables. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First_Name': ['Agatha', 'Agatha','Hercule', 'Hercule'],...                    
                   'Last Name': ['Christie', 'Raisin', 'Poirot', 'Holmes']})
```

I want some kind of data product that shows me:

```
Agatha: ['Christie', 'Raisin']
Hercule: ['Poirot', 'Holmes']
```

I would like to be able to do this without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('First_Name',as_index=False)['Last Name'].agg(list)
```

```
    First_Name  Last Name
0   Agatha  [Christie, Raisin]
1   Hercule     [Poirot, Holmes]
```

with removing duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby('First_Name',as_index=False)['Last Name'].agg(list)
```

Checking duplicates on First_Name and Last Name only

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['First_Name','Last Name']).groupby('First_Name',as_index=False)['Last Name'].agg(list)
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the values are sometimes repeated? How can I get it to give me only unique values?

Comment: duplicate how? you meant two rows of Poirot with Hercule?

Comment: Yes, I have a much larger dataset so if the same last name is associated with the first name more than once, I only want it to appear once.

Comment: Okay, but dropping duplicates only works if the other fields are also duplicates. For my purposes, I changed the syntax to df.groupby(['First_Name'])['Last Name'].unique().agg(list)

Comment: Sure, you can list these two attributes in a subset attribute of drop_duplicates as well.